# Getting error - Cannot resolve method 'getInstance' in 'FirebaseAuthException'

Tags: java, android, firebase

Getting error when trying to fAuth = FirebaseAuthException.getInstance();

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuthException fAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        fAuth = FirebaseAuthException.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: FirebaseAuthException does not have a `getInstance()` method. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() doesnt work too, maybe i have to import something else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using `FirebaseAuth` instead of `FirebaseAuthException`. Use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` to obtain a reference to the `FirebaseAuth` object to then make subsequent calls like `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` on.